# Why does PTRACE_PEEKUSER not allow reading of FPU registers on x86_64?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ptrace

`PTRACE_PEEKUSER` is documented to read a word from the `user` area, whose partial layout on x86_64 is:

```
struct user
{
  struct user_regs_struct       regs;
  int                           u_fpvalid;
  struct user_fpregs_struct     i387;
  //...
  int                           u_debugreg [8];
};
```

While one can happily call `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` with an offset which lies within `regs` or `u_debugreg`, passing an offset which is within `i387` returns `EIO` unconditionally.

Looking at the code in the kernel, I can see that reading inside `regs` and `u_debugreg` are the only supported offsets:

```
    case PTRACE_PEEKUSR: {
        unsigned long tmp;

        ret = -EIO;
        if ((addr & (sizeof(data) - 1)) || addr >= sizeof(struct user))
            break;

        tmp = 0;  /* Default return condition */
        if (addr < sizeof(struct user_regs_struct))
            tmp = getreg(child, addr);
        else if (addr >= offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[0]) &&
             addr <= offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[7])) {
            addr -= offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[0]);
            tmp = ptrace_get_debugreg(child, addr / sizeof(data));
        }
        ret = put_user(tmp, datap);
        break;
    }
```

I know that reading inside `i387` is not supported. I know that I can read those registers by calling `PTRACE_GETFPREGS` instead. My question is: is there a specific reason why reading those registers using `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` and writing them with `PTRACE_POKEUSER` is disabled?

My guess is that it's because most of the fields in `user_fpregs_struct` are smaller than 64 bits, therefore reads and writes may cover multiple registers. However, I'm writing a resource which will be public and will have a note on this, so I'd rather be certain that my guess is right.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: You want to read the Math Co-processor registers. Have you checked when the `i387` member of `struct user` in the kernel gets updated? I haven't, and I could be wrong, but my guess is not often, but in cases like core dumps, for example.

From arch/x86/include/asm/user_64.h

```
struct user {
/* We start with the registers, to mimic the way that "memory" is returned
   from the ptrace(3,...) function.  */
  struct user_regs_struct regs; /* Where the registers are actually stored */
/* ptrace does not yet supply these.  Someday.... */
  int u_fpvalid;        /* True if math co-processor being used. */
                /* for this mess. Not yet used. */
  int pad0;
  struct user_i387_struct i387; /* Math Co-processor registers. */
  :
  unsigned long u_debugreg[8];
  :
};
```

So, reading Math Co-processor registers is best done by reading from the FPU. If you check how kernel does the `PTRACE_GETFPREGS`, you'll see it's getting it from FPU, and not the `struct user` `i387` member. Same goes for writing Math Co-processor registers using `PTRACE_SETFPREGS`.

From `arch_ptrace`

```
case PTRACE_GETFPREGS:  /* Get the child FPU state. */
    return copy_regset_to_user(child,
                   task_user_regset_view(current),
                   REGSET_FP,
                   0, sizeof(struct user_i387_struct),
                   datap);
```

`task_user_regset_view` return `x86_64_regsets` that uses `xfpregs_get` for reading.

```
static struct user_regset x86_64_regsets[] __ro_after_init = {

    [REGSET_FP] = {
        .core_note_type = NT_PRFPREG,
        .n = sizeof(struct user_i387_struct) / sizeof(long),
        .size = sizeof(long), .align = sizeof(long),
        .active = regset_xregset_fpregs_active, .regset_get = xfpregs_get, .set = xfpregs_set
    },

}

const struct user_regset_view *task_user_regset_view(struct task_struct *task)
{
    :
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_64
    return &user_x86_64_view;
#endif
}
```